# For Metricbeat Prometheus module, Using metricsets as query in prometheus.yml output giving one result, although multiple queries are present

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, metricbeat

I have configured metricbeat and enabled prometheus module. In prometheus.yml I have added multiple queries

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-prometheus-query.html

**But I am getting only one query output for "metricbeat test modules" command and also in elasticsearch.**

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Attaching the prometheus.yml and command output for metricbeat test modules:

```html
# Module: prometheus
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/8.2/metricbeat-module-prometheus.html

- module: prometheus
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["localhost:9090"]
  metricsets: ["query"]
  queries:
  - name: "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total"
  - name: "container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total"
  - name: "container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total"
  - name: "container_cpu_load_average_10s"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_load_average_10s"
  - name: "container_cpu_system_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_system_seconds_total"
  - name: "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total"
  - name: "container_cpu_user_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_cpu_user_seconds_total"
  - name: "container_spec_cpu_period"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_cpu_period"
  - name: "container_spec_cpu_quota"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_cpu_quota"
  - name: "container_spec_cpu_shares"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_cpu_shares"
  - name: "go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction"
  - name: "machine_cpu_cores"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "machine_cpu_cores"
  - name: "machine_cpu_physical_cores"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "machine_cpu_physical_cores"
  - name: "machine_cpu_sockets"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "machine_cpu_sockets"
  - name: "node_cpu_guest_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_cpu_guest_seconds_total"
  - name: "node_cpu_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_cpu_seconds_total"
  - name: "process_cpu_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "process_cpu_seconds_total"
  - name: "container_memory_cache"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_cache"
  - name: "container_memory_failcnt"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_failcnt"
  - name: "container_memory_failures_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_failures_total"
  - name: "container_memory_mapped_file"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_mapped_file"
  - name: "container_memory_max_usage_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_max_usage_bytes"
  - name: "container_memory_rss"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_rss"
  - name: "container_memory_swap"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_swap"
  - name: "container_memory_usage_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_usage_bytes"
  - name: "container_memory_working_set_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_memory_working_set_bytes"
  - name: "container_spec_memory_limit_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_memory_limit_bytes"
  - name: "container_spec_memory_reservation_limit_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_memory_reservation_limit_bytes"
  - name: "container_spec_memory_swap_limit_bytes"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "container_spec_memory_swap_limit_bytes"
  - name: "node_disk_info"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_info"
  - name: "node_disk_io_now"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_io_now"
  - name: "node_disk_io_time_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_io_time_seconds_total"
  - name: "node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total"
  - name: "node_disk_read_bytes_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_read_bytes_total"
  - name: "node_disk_read_time_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_read_time_seconds_total"
  - name: "node_disk_reads_completed_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_reads_completed_total"
  - name: "node_disk_reads_merged_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_reads_merged_total"
  - name: "node_disk_write_time_seconds_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_write_time_seconds_total"
  - name: "node_disk_writes_completed_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_writes_completed_total"
  - name: "node_disk_writes_merged_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_writes_merged_total"
  - name: "node_disk_written_bytes_total"
    path: "/api/v1/query"
    params:
      query: "node_disk_written_bytes_total"        
  #username: "user"
  #password: "secret"

  # This can be used for service account based authorization:
  #bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  #ssl.certificate_authorities:
  #  - /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt

  # Use Elasticsearch histogram type to store histograms (beta, default: false)
  # This will change the default layout and put metric type in the field name
  #use_types: true

  # Store counter rates instead of original cumulative counters (experimental, default: false)
  #rate_counters: true

# Metrics sent by a Prometheus server using remote_write option
#- module: prometheus
#  metricsets: ["remote_write"]
#  host: "localhost"
#  port: "9201"

  # Secure settings for the server using TLS/SSL:
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/server/cert.pem"
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/server/cert.key"

  # Use Elasticsearch histogram type to store histograms (beta, default: false)
  # This will change the default layout and put metric type in the field name
  #use_types: true

  # Store counter rates instead of original cumulative counters (experimental, default: false)
  #rate_counters: true

  # Define patterns for counter and histogram types so as to identify metrics' types according to these patterns
  #types_patterns:
  #  counter_patterns: []
  #  histogram_patterns: []

# Metrics that will be collected using a PromQL
#- module: prometheus
#  metricsets: ["query"]
#  hosts: ["localhost:9090"]
#  period: 10s
#  queries:
#  - name: "instant_vector"
#    path: "/api/v1/query"
#    params:
#      query: "sum(rate(prometheus_http_requests_total[1m]))"
#  - name: "range_vector"
#    path: "/api/v1/query_range"
#    params:
#      query: "up"
#      start: "2019-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"
#      end:  "2019-12-21T00:00:00.000Z"
#      step: 1h
#  - name: "scalar"
#    path: "/api/v1/query"
#    params:
#      query: "100"
#  - name: "string"
#    path: "/api/v1/query"
#    params:
#      query: "some_value"
```

Where in localhost:9090 prometheus server running in local.

**Output for metricbeat test modules:**

```html
% metricbeat test modules    
prometheus...
  query...OK
    result: 
    {
     "@timestamp": "2022-11-18T12:23:30.000Z",
     "event": {
      "dataset": "prometheus.query",
      "duration": 16597958,
      "module": "prometheus"
     },
     "metricset": {
      "name": "query",
      "period": 10000
     },
     "prometheus": {
      "labels": {
       "__name__": "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total",
       "beta_kubernetes_io_arch": "arm64",
       "beta_kubernetes_io_os": "linux",
       "id": "/",
       "instance": "minikube",
       "job": "kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor",
       "kubernetes_io_arch": "arm64",
       "kubernetes_io_hostname": "minikube",
       "kubernetes_io_os": "linux",
       "minikube_k8s_io_commit": "362d5fdc0a3dbee389b3d3f1034e8023e72bd3a7",
       "minikube_k8s_io_name": "minikube",
       "minikube_k8s_io_primary": "true",
       "minikube_k8s_io_updated_at": "2022_06_14T13_02_04_0700",
       "minikube_k8s_io_version": "v1.25.2"
      },
      "query": {
       "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total": 13846766
      }
     },
     "service": {
      "address": "http://localhost:9090",
      "type": "prometheus"
     }
    }
```

**Output for ElasticSearch:**

```html
% curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/metricbeat-*/_search?pretty' | grep query -A 12

% curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/metricbeat-*/_search?pretty' | grep query -A 12
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 35829  100 35829    0     0  4513k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11.3M
            "dataset" : "prometheus.query",
            "module" : "prometheus",
            "duration" : 298962583
          },
          "metricset" : {
            "name" : "query",
            "period" : 10000
          },
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "8.0.0"
          },
          "host" : {
            "architecture" : "x86_64",
            "os" : {
              "version" : "12.6",
              "family" : "darwin",
              "name" : "macOS",
              "kernel" : "21.6.0",
--
            "query" : {
              "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total" : 1428357.0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : ".ds-metricbeat-8.2.3-2022.11.18-000001",
        "_id" : "PYzZiYQBDDMX1_hMzj26",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2022-11-18T08:27:42.000Z",
          "host" : {
--
            "dataset" : "prometheus.query",
            "module" : "prometheus",
            "duration" : 299000750
          },
          "metricset" : {
            "name" : "query",
            "period" : 10000
          },
          "service" : {
            "address" : "http://dev-prom.aiops-dev-iks-8ba09efe74c02599dc0e70964024f60f-0000.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud",
            "type" : "prometheus"
          },
          "prometheus" : {
            "labels" : {
              "instance" : "10.72.120.195:10250",
              "node" : "10.72.120.195",
              "service" : "mcmp-kps-kubelet",
              "__name__" : "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total",
--
            "query" : {
              "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total" : 203219
            }
          },
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "8.0.0"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : ".ds-metricbeat-8.2.3-2022.11.18-000001",
        "_id" : "PozZiYQBDDMX1_hMzj26",
        "_score" : 1.0,
--
            "dataset" : "prometheus.query",
            "module" : "prometheus"
          },
          "metricset" : {
            "name" : "query",
            "period" : 10000
          },
          "service" : {
            "address" : "http://dev-prom.aiops-dev-iks-8ba09efe74c02599dc0e70964024f60f-0000.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud",
            "type" : "prometheus"
          },
          "prometheus" : {
            "labels" : {
              "__name__" : "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total",
              "container" : "config-reloader",
              "instance" : "10.72.120.195:10250",
              "metrics_path" : "/metrics/cadvisor",
--
            "query" : {
              "container_cpu_cfs_periods_total" : 272986
            }
          }
        }
      },
```